# open a man page in linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

How to open then man page of mkdir from terminal . I want the manual entry given in the following [link](http://home.fhtw-berlin.de/~junghans/cref/MAN/mkdir.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give like this.

```
  man 2 mkdir
```

From the `man` page of `man`

> 1   Executable programs or shell commands
>
> 2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>
> 3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>
> 4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>
> 5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>
> 6   Games
>
> 7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
>
> 8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
>
> 9   Kernel routines [Non standard]

You need to open the system call , so you have to mention that as 2. If you give like this, `man mkdir` then it will open the `man` page of `mkdir` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the man page from the terminal using the `man` command.

```
man 2 mkdir
```

For more details you can use `man man`.